# How to fix else if in javascript that is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help. I want to change the button style on the event 'onclick'

Here is my HTML

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="on">
                                    <button href="#" id="btn1" onclick="control1()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="off">
                                    <button href="#" id="btn2" onclick="control2()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lightbulb"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="off">
                                    <button href="#" id="btn3" onclick="control3()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="off">
                                    <button href="#" id="btn4" onclick="control4()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-snowflake"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="on">
                                    <button href="#" id="btn5" onclick="control5()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

And here is the css

```
#sha_button_list ul li.off button
{
    color:rgba(49,69,106, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
                -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

#sha_button_list ul li.on button
{
    color: rgba(49,69,106, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7),
                -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1),
                0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
                0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}
```

And the last is the javascript

```
<script>
            function switches(x)
            { 

                if(x.style.color = "rgba(49,69,106, 0.35)")
                    {
                        x.style.cssText = "color: rgba(49,69,106, 1);box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7),-0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01);";
                    }
                else if(x.style.color = "rgba(49,69,106, 1)")
                    {
                        x.style.cssText = "color: rgba(49,69,106, 0.35);box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);";
                    }


            }

            function control1()
            {
                switches(document.getElementById("btn1"));
            }
            function control2()
            {
                switches(document.getElementById("btn2"));
            }
            function control3()
            {
                switches(document.getElementById("btn3"));
            }
            function control4()
            {
                switches(document.getElementById("btn4"));
            }
            function control5()
            {
                switches(document.getElementById("btn5"));
            }

        </script>
```

The thing that only work is the if condition. I've tried to change the condition of if and else if, but only the condition of if that is work. I've also tried using else, but it also doesn't work. Please help me to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: `x.style.color = "rgba(49,69,106, 0.35)"` `=` should be `==`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the assignment operator `=` in your predicate, instead of the strict-equality comparison operator `===` or the loose-equality comparison operator `==`.

```js
// broken
if (x.style.color = "rgba(49,69,106, 0.35)")
```

```js
// works
if (x.style.color === "rgba(49,69,106, 0.35)")
```

May I recommend that you install and use `eslint`, which will help you catch these types of errors early on.

Comment: Avoid answering typo questions, flag instead

Comment: Thank you for answering. But it still doesn't work bro